# How to correctly interpret recursive pseudo code for a hashing scheme

Tags: php, hash, syntax, cryptography

I try to follow [this paper](http://sec.cs.ucl.ac.uk/users/smurdoch/papers/protocols08cookies.pdf) (Hardened Stateless Session Cookies by Murdoch) to realize a salting mechanism. The following pseudo code describes the code:

> ```
> a[0](salt, password ) = H(salt||password )  
> a[x](salt, password ) = H(a[x−1](salt, password )||password )
> ```
>
> H: Cryptographically secure hash function
>   x: Hash iteration count
>   a: Authenticator
>   salt: Per-account, cryptographically secure pseudorandom number about 128bit
>   password: User pw in cleartext

I wonder if the php implementation shall be the following:

```
$a0 = hash('sha256', $salt | $password);
$auth = recursiveHash($a0, $password, 256)

function recursiveHash($salt, $password, $counter) {
    if ($counter === 0) {
        return hash('sha256', $salt | $password);
    } else {
        $counter--;
        return $this->recursiveHash(hash('sha256', $salt | $password), $password, $counter);
    }
}
```

In general: I do struggle with the exact syntactic interpretation. What does a $varOne, $varTwo mean? Is it the result of the last function call? Is a || a bitwise OR Operator? Why not a single |? What does the following mean:

```
c = a[n](salt, password )
```

Is it the same (when n == x) as:

```
a[x](salt, password ) = H(a[x−1](salt, password )||password )
```

Would be very happy, if someone could help me with the semantic and syntactic interpretation of this paper.

Comment: So basically you are trying to create a salted hash. In order to do that you need just concatenate the password you get from the form with a secure randomly generated salt. The main idea behind is to have different hashes for the same password.  If you are a beginner with this kind of stuff take care because it is very easy to get it wrong: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q

Comment: I think I am aware of password storing problems in general. My question is, if the salting in this special case is added by bitwise OR operation or by a classic append. And more general, how to exactly read the pseudocode of the paper.

Comment: I don't see any `$varOne, $varTwo` in your question? Where are those defined? Where did `a[n]` originate from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have:

```
a[0](salt, password) = H(salt || password )  
a[x](salt, password) = H(a[x−1](salt, password) || password)
```

First note that `||` means concatenation in this case. Bit operands don't make sense here, as you don't want to delete bits of the password.

Then lets take a look what happens if `n` has value `2`:

```
a[0](salt, password) = H(salt || password )
a[1](salt, password) = H(a[1−1](salt, password) || password) = H(a[0](salt, password) || password) = H(H(salt || password) || password)
a[2](salt, password) = H(a[1](salt, password) || password) = H(H(H(salt || password) || password) || password)
```

So as you can see you can simply reuse the previous hash value, add the password bytes to them, and hash again.

Generally you should not use a recursive method for this. You don't need to backtrack, and the iteration count `n` is usually pretty high. That would mean high memory requirements for a recursive function, while the intermediate values do not have to be kept.

Finally, in your code you use the `salt` variable as input for the intermediate hash values. That's incorrect, there is only one `salt`, and that's the one you start with. Furthermore, you should make sure that you apply a specific [character-encoding](/questions/tagged/character-encoding) over the password.